# Accumulator for outer nested loop Python

Tags: python, loops, nested, accumulator

I'm learning python on my own from a book and solving problems. In one problem, the user inputs amount of rain for each month in one year across a period of years. I need to find the average of rain in each year (sum(monthly rain)/numb_months, and also the average of rain in that period, e.g. in two years. In the following code, I can get the average for each year (I used 3 months only instead of 12 months to avoid tedious input now), but I don't know where I need to put an accumulator for total rain in that period and then average it. I appreciate your help.

```
number_of_months = 3
years_in_period = int(input("Please enter the number of years in the period. \n"))

for year in range(years_in_period):
    yearly_rain = 0
    print('Year', year+1) 
    print('−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−')
    for month in range(number_of_months):
        print('Month', month+1, end='')
        monthly_rain = float(input("Please enter rainfall for this month: \n"))
        yearly_rain += monthly_rain
        average_yearly_rainfall = yearly_rain / number_of_months
    print("Average yearly rainfall of year ", year+1, " is ", average_yearly_rainfall)
    print("Year total rain is", yearly_rain)
    print()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood what you want (to calculate the absolute average of the rain amount during the period), this should do the trick:

```
number_of_months = 3
years_in_period = int(input("Please enter the number of years in the period. \n"))

total_rain = 0

for year in range(years_in_period):
    yearly_rain = 0
    print('Year', year+1) 
    print('−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−')

    for month in range(number_of_months):
        print('Month', month+1, end='')
        monthly_rain = float(input("Please enter rainfall for this month: \n"))

        yearly_rain += monthly_rain

        total_rain += monthly_rain

        average_yearly_rainfall = yearly_rain / number_of_months

    print("Average yearly rainfall of year ", year+1, " is ", average_yearly_rainfall)
    print("Year total rain is", yearly_rain)
    print()


total_months = years_in_period * number_of_months
print("Absolute average of rain/month was", total_rain/total_months)
print("Absolute average of rain/year was", total_rain/years_in_period)
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for! Thank you so much, Pedro Martins for quick help!

Comment: No problem! Just let me know if you need something else ;)